# How to create wallets using private keys in Venom Chrome extension

Tags: blockchain, private-key

I am working with this library for the Venom Hackathon https://github.com/tonlabs/ever-sdk-js and created a few keypairs using the functions it has.

```
import { TonClient } from "@eversdk/core";
import { libNode } from "@eversdk/lib-node";

  TonClient.useBinaryLibrary(libNode);
  const client = new TonClient();
  const keys = await client.crypto.generate_random_sign_keys();
```

The keypairs got created, now can I import this in the Venom Wallet Chrome extension so that I get the keypair in my wallet. I am looking for the feature of importing wallet using the private key.

Answer (score 0):

Venom Wallet doesn't allow to import account using private key. You can generate the `Mnemonic` using this

```
const keys = await client.crypto.mnemonic_from_random({});
```

then go to **Venom Wallet** -> **Profile** -> **Manage Seed** -> **Add New** -> **Import Seed**